# Cassandra Scala Spark - saving RDD to Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I have the following RDD

```
RDD[(String, Seq[((String, Double), Int)])]
```

An example would be:

```
RDD["a", Seq[(("b", 2.0), 1), (("c", 3.0), 2)]]
```

And I want to insert into my Cassandra table with the following schema

```
String (PK), String, Double, Int
```

In the end, for the given example, I will have the following in my DB

```
"a", "b", 2.0, 1
"a", "c", 3.0, 2
```

What is the Scala code which does this? I tried to use `saveToCassandra`, but my input isn't in the form of `RDD[(String, String, Double, Int)]`. Should I first flatten it?

Answer (score 1):

All you need here is a `flatMap`:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val rdd: RDD[(String, Seq[((String, Double), Int)])] = ???
val flattened: RDD[(String, String, Double, Int)] = rdd.flatMap{
  case (k, vs) => vs.map{case ((v1, v2), v3) => (k, v1, v2, v3)}}
```